# Autocomplete Ajax call in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

HTML file (using Laravel's blade):

```js
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <div class="input-group" id="search-form">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon1">Search:</span>
                        <input type="text" name="search" size="1" id="search-bar" class="form-control" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        @if ( !empty($search) )
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($search_query as $item)
                                        <li><a href="{{ url('shop/' . $item->url . '/' . $item->purl) }}">{{ $item->ptitle }}</a></li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        @endif
                        <button class="btn input-group-text" id="submit-btn">Go!</button>
                    </div>
```

Method inside the controller:

```js
    public function search(Request $request){
    
        Product::autoComplete($request, self::$data);
        return self::$data;
    
      }
```

[image]

The problem I'm having with it is that I cannot get inside the `@if (!empty($search))` although there is a variable `$search` containing the information from the Ajax call (as can be seen in the screenshot attached).

The ultimate goal is to show to the user all the terms that matches his/her search in a `div` below the search input (kinda like the search bar on YouTube).

Here is the rest of the code, although it's working correctly as can be seen from the screenshot of the `dd(self::$data)`:

**Model:**

```js
 static public function autoComplete($request, &$data){
        if ( !empty( $request['search'] ) && is_string($request['search'])) {
  
            $search = trim(filter_var($request['search'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
            $search = strtoupper($search);
            
           
            
            if ($search) {
              
              $data['search'] = DB::table('products AS p')
              ->join('categories AS c', 'c.id', '=', 'p.categorie_id')
              ->select('ptitle', 'article', 'c.url', 'p.purl')
              ->where('ptitle', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
              ->orWhere('article', 'LIKE', '%' .$search . '%')
              ->get();
              
            }
            
          }
    }
```

**Web router:**

```html
Route::get('search', 'PageController@search');
```

Comment: Where are you passing `$search` to the view?

Comment: in self::$data.

Comment: It looks like you are not returning $data in your model.  Try return $data; after ->get();

Comment: $data runs by reference in the model (notice the parameters of the function).
also $data is constructed by the parent controller through magic method __construct